# PyChef - Is there REST API to get chef-client runs

Tags: python, chef-infra, pychef

I am trying to pull chef-client runs details. We are using PyChef currently and able to get information on the list of nodes connected with the Chef Server and its corresponding run_list. Is there an option in PyChef to get information on the client runs (start time, end time, status of the run, etc)

Used the following code:

```
import chef

with chef.ChefAPI('Chef_Master URL', '#Perm_file#', 'User_name',ssl_verify=False):

        for node in chef.Node.list():
            node = chef.Node(node)
            print node.list
            print node.run_list
```

Comment: Please fix your code snippet indentation - in Python indentation is significative and as is your code would raise a SyntaxError. If even Python cannot understand it, no one can ;)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers fixed indentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Chef Server does not save that information. It is part of the older Chef Reporting commercial addon and the newer Chef Automate system. As I've never used either, there is no direct API support for those in PyChef but you can always use the raw API object to make simple requests yourself. For example, looking at https://docs.chef.io/api_reporting.html#reports-nodes-node-runs you could use `api['/reports/nodes/foo.example.com/runs']` to get a list of the run IDs for that node.